# Trying to compile Android non native project with NSight

Tags: android, visual-studio, nvidia, nsight, tegra

I am trying to compile a plain and simple Android Application WITHOUT native code using the new nsight plugin with visual studio.
The problem is visual studio wont even try to compile as it doesn't see anything to compile. Running ant debug manually compiles it fine.
The Android application with native code works fine, as visual studio recognizes the c file as something to compile.
Does anyone know how to fix this, because as is, the Android Application without Native code option is rather useless.

The output is

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Android3, Configuration: Debug Android ------
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I should also note if I go into command line, and run ant build, it builds fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try a helloworld sample from the template "Android Application", see if that compiles.

If you installed Nsight Tegra from Tegra Android Development Pack, and also installed Android SDK/NDK, ANT, JAVA from that. They should be preconfigured working.
Basically you need 32bit java in your path, and JAVA_HOME,ANT_HOME environments. As you have seen native compiled, most likely the java related are missed or messed in your environments.

As you described "no compiling", is there any other log in output?

Comment: That's not enough detail. But mostly you missed ant in VS. You can check Tools\Option\Android\General, ensure all paths there are correct.

Comment: Yes they are ALL correct, and as I stated before, the native, which includes java AND C, compiled fine, with the same settings. As I stated in OP,the problem seems to be that visual studio is not even TRYING to compile, unless there is a C file in there.

Comment: Ok. Then have you tried the Android Application project template? Does that work out of box?  If the error still persist for you, I recommend you to post on https://devtalk.nvidia.com/ and attach your project.  There should have someone to assist finding the root cause.

Comment: That is the project template I am using. And will do that thankyou

Comment: Also check "Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions\Build and Run\MSBuild project output verbosity" to "Diagnostic", then "Rebuild All", see if that helps producing more meaningful output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24798/discussion-between-nekosune-and-xuan-wang)